# locomotive.js smooth scroll update() on load

Tags: smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll

I'm using locomotive.js (https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) on a wordpress site.
It worked perfectly until I uploaded to a live server. On the live server the elements sometimes bump into each other and then flicker and disappear and the footer is also cut off.

I think it must something to do with the page not loading and I need to use update() to check whether the page is loaded. But I'm not sure how to change this to check for page load rather than timeout - can anyone help?

```
function smooth() {
 let scrollContainer = document.querySelector('your-selector');
scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
el: scrollContainer,
smooth: true    });

setTimeout(() => {
   scroll.update();
}, 500); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

we have to detect images and large assets to load  You should use   [imageLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)  to detect all image loading and after then you have to update the scroll   and it should work fine

```
  const imagesLoaded = require("imagesloaded"); // import the library or can use cdn


  let scrollContainer = document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]");

  var scroll;

  scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: scrollContainer,
    smooth: true,
    getSpeed: true,
    getDirection: true,
    offset:["15%",0]
  });




  /* update scroll (height) when all images are loaded */

  imagesLoaded(scrollContainer, { background: true }, function () {
    scroll.update();
  });
```